# How to get vertical scroll in Ionic slide box

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to swipe sideways between sections of a questionnaire. Each section has a header and a number of answered questions. I would like to add a vertical scroll on the questions, but can't figure out how to get it working. Here is my view:

```
  <ion-view title="{{vm.title}}">
    <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" class="has-header">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="s in vm.sections">
            <ion-item class="item-royal">
                {{s.Heading}}
            </ion-item>
            <ion-scroll>
                <div class="card" ng-repeat="q in s.Questions">
                    <div class="item item-divider">
                        {{q.Text}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        {{q.Answer}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-scroll>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution that fixes the specific problem I was having, but creates another. I added a div to the ion-scroll and set heights on the ion-scroll and the new div:

```
<ion-scroll style="height:300px">
    <div style="height:100%">
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="q in s.Questions">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                {{q.Text}}
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                {{q.Answer}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

This causes two problems:

1. I don't want to specify the height of the ion-scroll in pixels - I'd like it to fill the remaining space in the window.
2. The pager appears in front of the scroll window - I'd like it to appear below.

**EDIT** Then I found a second solution:

```
 <ion-view title="{{vm.title}}">
        <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" class="has-header" 
                       style="position:absolute; bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0; ">
            <ion-slide ng-repeat="s in vm.sections">
                <ion-item class="item-royal">
                    {{s.Heading}}
                </ion-item>
                <ion-content>
                    <div class="card" ng-repeat="q in s.Questions">
                        <div class="item item-divider">
                            {{q.Text}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            {{q.Answer}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-view>
```

Changes made

1. Set the style of the `ion-slide-box` to `position:absolute; bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;` (The top is already specified by the `has-header` class)
2. Use ion-content around the part I want to scroll instead of the `ion-scroll` and the `div`
3. Live with the pager in front. It looks fine!

**Edit 2**
I'd also recommend using [Crosswalk](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/) if you are having scroll problems with older Android devices.

Comment: FWIW I didn't even add the styles specified for the second solution - adding an `<ion-content>` section was enough.

Comment: i found when doing this that the ion-content scrolls "forever" is there a way to stop that, or are you not seeing it?

Answer (score 4):

For Ionic 4 get it to scroll vertically with some css.

```
<ion-slide><div class="scrollVertically">stuff to scroll...</div></ion-slide>

.scrollVertically{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I found for Ionic 4, since they deprecated <ion-scroll>. And it even takes care of the "auto-scroll-to-top-on-slide" problem. No need for that, cause every slide has it's own scroll box.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this with this simple css:

ion-slides { height: initial; }

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 2, you need to use `<ion-slides>`. `<ion-slide-box>` has been deprecated.

Comment: As of September 2016 Ionic 2 is still in Beta, and I don't want to switch until it gets a full release. Nonetheless, since it is deprecated, I decided to change to ion-slides in my 1.3 app. It took away my specific scroll problem. But replaced it with many others. In older Android versions (4.1 - 4.2), the window did not resize when elements were shown, making elements inaccessible. The current slide was getting superimposed on the previous slide, so I added show/hide logic using Angular. But that doesn't work on swipe. Can't say I'd recommend using ion-slides in Ionic 1.3